# Redis - best way to cache the data

Tags: redis

I have 3 types of values.

```
Type1 - In millions
Type2 - In hundreds
Type3 - In tens
```

For each type1, all type2 should be processed by type3.

I can use set.

```
Type1#Type3 = {Type2 values}
```

Or

```
Type1#Type2 = {Type3 values}
```

If I keep Type3 as a key, more memory occupied by the set.

Or is there any better way to store this type data?

I evaluated hash which occupies more memory than set. I evaluated with ziplist compression for hash.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can tolerate splitting, here is another way:

First HashMap with key as a type1 value and value as a `:` separated list of type2 values linked to that type 1 value

`type1_a => type2_b:type2_c..`

`type1_b => type2_k:type2_d..`

Second HashMap with key as a type2 value and value as the corresponding type3 value

`type2_a => type3a`

`type3_b => type3b`

`for type2_key in firstHashMap.get(type1_key).split(':')
    secondHasMap.get(type2_key)`

Also, you can look into Lua script to avoid doing the above on client side.